# How to pass Data or Position of Spinner from Activity to ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have created an activity where I have taken one spinner. Now I want to pass the data (string name or Position int) from the selected item in the spinner to one listFragment. I tried using Bundle and getActivity() into the Fragment, but the data is not passing. I know this is crude but I am new to Android Programming. Thank You!
  (P.S. I have used Radio Group As Well To Switch Between 2 Spinners)

```
public class HighScore extends Activity {

TextView t;
RadioGroup r;
int pos,pos1,value;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter, adapter1;
Spinner spinner,spinner1;
String[] classic,arcade;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    r = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    classic = new String[]{"Easy", "Hard"};
    arcade = new String[]{"30", "60", "90"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classic);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classic);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    r.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            pos = r.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:

                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classic);


                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    spinner.getOnItemSelectedListener();

                    break;

                case 1:

                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arcade);


                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    break;

            }
        }
    });


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment1, Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), FragEasy.class.getName())).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment1, Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), FragHard.class.getName())).commit();
                    break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Read about `setArgument()` method for fragment transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add or replace fragments based on your spinner value like this :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                 FragEasy fragEasy = new FragEasy();
                 ft =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() ;
                 ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragEasy).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragHard = new FragHard();
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragHard).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Also make sure the container for the fragment is a framelayout which will be replaced by your respective fragment

```
<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/fragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a bundle in the activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("TAG", *position/value as string here* );

// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And for this to work your fragment should get bundle as a parameter on **onCreateView** function. If you do not need the bundle all the time you can say if bundle null then do not do this part or something else that you need there.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

So that you set the bundle for your fragment which can now use it as you please again by converting it back to string.

```
String _strBundle = _bundle.toString();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank You It Worked

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass spinner select Item on Your Fragment Constructor like this.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     //get selected spinner value.
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment1, Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), FragEasy.class.getName(),selected_value)).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment1, Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), FragHard.class.getName(),selected_value)).commit();
                    break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```